# How can I join these two select statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

First statement

```
SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE Region = 'x' AND level > 2 ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

Second statement

```
SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE Region = 'x' AND level < 3 ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

Comment: Why not one query: WHERE `level` BETWEEN 2 AND 3;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can UNION them.

```
(SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE Region = 'x' AND level > 2 ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0,6)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE Region = 'x' AND level < 3 ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0,6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldnt the "obvious" solution be to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE Region = 'x' AND (level > 2 OR level < 3) ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

or alternative like Remco mentioned with between:

```
SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE Region = 'x' AND NOT (level BETWEEN 2 AND 3) ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: No because I wanted to get maximum 6 of those under level 3 and maximum 6 of those above level 2.
If there were 4 under level 3 and 8 above level 2 your query would give me the output of 12 objects, meanwhile the right query as written on top would give me the output of 10 objects.